How to resolve Unable to start receiver MyReceiver: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object MyTestObject
The app is designed to create local notification based on various circumstances. MyReceiver class extends BroadCastReceiver. in onReceive method of the MyReceiver class i'm getting the intent value using
intent?.let {

                val notification: MyTestObject? =
                   ** (it.extras?.getBundle(BUNDLE) as Bundle).serializable(** // Crash occurs in this line
                        NOTIFICATION, MyTestObject::class.java
                    ) as MyTestObject?
}

.serializable is a utility class where the code looks like this
fun <T : Serializable> Bundle.serializable(key: String, clazz: Class<T>) =
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        this.getSerializable(key, clazz)
    } else {
        **@Suppress("DEPRECATION") this.getSerializable(key)** // Crash occurs in this line
    }

MyTestObject extends a Serializable that contains parameters to show title, message and some other info for showing the notificaiton
Firebase logged crash like this
Caused by java.io.InvalidClassException
package.MyTestObject ; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 5633808751232699642, local class serialVersionUID = 2428744743958317109
inorder to resolve this error we added private const val serialVersionUID: Long = 5633808751232699642 to the MyTestObject.
But now we are getting the same crash like this
Caused by java.io.InvalidClassException
com.abbvie.mycare.notifications.domain.entity.MyCareNotification; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 2428744743958317109, local class serialVersionUID = 5633808751232699642
